# Doctrine Undefined index: UnitOfWork.php line 2873

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle with Symfony2. I'm attempting to use the Registration Email Confirmation functionality. When I hit the /confirmation/{confirmationToken} url Doctrine throws the following exception

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000006553367d000000005133f603 in /Users/jacobspizziri/Documents/Projects/SRC3/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2873
```

This occurs when it tries to hash the Group entity I constructed here:

```
spl_object_hash($entity)
```

and $entity looks like this:

[image: sorry it looks so small]

Here are the relations I have setup in my entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * 
 * @author jacobspizziri
 */
class Group implements SoftDeletableInterface, TimestampableInterface {

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SRC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="group", cascade={"all"})
   */
   protected $users;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements SoftDeletableInterface, TimestampableInterface
{   

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SRC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $group;
}
```

My bundle extends FOSUserBundle however I am not extending FOSUserBundle\Entity\Group for my Group

whats going on here?